# With Field Layout, Display Suite, and Panels deprecated how does one change the layout of a form display to be more than a single column?

Tags: layout-builder

I am working on Drupal 10.1 and without Field Layout, Display Suite, and Panels modules installed there are not options to change the layout settings beyond the Content and Disabled sections.
What other options are there to change the form display layout to add additional columns?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/layout-builder

Comment: Layout builder is not an option under form display.